# RDWeb and RemoteApp: How to launch RemoteApp after RDWeb login?

Tags: windows-server-2012-r2, remoteapp, rdweb

I have Windows Server 2012 R2 and RDWeb configured. If I login using RDWeb I can see my RemoteApp and I can launch it. What if I want to launch this RemoteApp automatically after login. How can I do it?

Answer (score 0):

First, you have to configure SSO on your server.

I recommend to follow this tutorial : https://nedimmehic.org/2017/11/20/remote-desktop-services-2016-standard-deployment-part-4-rd-web-access-part4-sso-high-availability/

After this, you have to modify some GPO for activate autologon. This link can help you : https://www.sevenforums.com/tutorials/141937-remote-desktop-connection-automatic-log-allow-prevent.html

Enjoy !

Comment: Hi and welcome on serverfault. Can you please edit your answer and sum up important points of the tuturials? links can become obsolete, not the content of your answer.